# how to trigger prop functions from inside FileDetailsComponent using RTL in react js unit testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import MultiSelectComponent from '../../shared/MultiSelectComponent';

  export default class FileDetailsComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myFormRef = React.createRef();
}
render() {
const {handleInputChange allCustomers,isEditMode} = this.props;
return (
    {!isEditMode ?
    <span className="form-control disabled">{this.getCustomersToShow()}</span>
     :
     allCustomers && allCustomers.length ?
                                                                 
     <MultiSelectComponent
     id="customer"
     data-testid="customer"
     noChipsView={true}
     hasSelectAll={true}
     disabled={!isEditMode}
     dropdownContent="customers"
     className={`multiselect-wrap ${formErrors && formErrors.customers ? 'has-error' : ''}`}
     options={allCustomers}
     selectedValues={editObj.customers}
     handleSelectChange={(selectedItems) => handleInputChange('customers', selectedItems)}
     placeholder="Select Customer(s)"
 />
: <span className="form-control disabled">{fileDetails.customers ? 
  this.getCustomersToShow() : 'N/A'}</span>
}
```

Please write unit test using RTL for this `handleSelectChange` prop function. I am unable to cover this function. I am trying to use customer for find the `getByTestId`

This is my test example!!

```
describe('FileDetailsComponent', () => {
it('should call handleInputChange with selected items', () => {
  const mockHandleInputChange = jest.fn();
  const allCustomers = [
    { label: 'Customer 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Customer 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Customer 3', value: '3' }
  ];
  const selectedItems = [allCustomers[0], allCustomers[2]]; // Example of selected items

  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <FileDetailsComponent
          editObj={editObj}
          handleInputChange={mockHandleInputChange}
          handleSelectChange={mockHandleInputChange}
          fileDetails={fileDetails}
          loading={false}
          allCustomers={allCustomers}
          isEditMode={true}
        />
      </Provider>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const multiSelect = screen.getByTestId('customer');
  console.log("multiSelect", multiSelect);
  fireEvent.change(multiSelect, { target: { selectedOptions: selectedItems } });
  expect(multiSelect).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(mockHandleInputChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('customers', selectedItems);
});
});
```